# Can't seem to understand why STUFF isn't working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got two tables that store questions and possible answers.
The questions table can have multiple possible answers to it.

I want to display the possible answers it can have per question..
For instance lets say I have two questions

```
1) Hows the weather?
2) Do you love MI?
```

And the other table I have possible answers

```
1) Good
1) Fair
2) Yes
2) No
```

My expecting result would be

```
1 Good, Fair
2 Yes, No
```

But instead I get:

```
1 Good, Fair, Yes, No
2 Yes, No, Good, Fair
```

Here's what I am doing...

```
SELECT x.SurveyQuestionID, PossibleAnswers = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + Answer FROM SurveyQuestionPossibleAnswer sqpa
    INNER JOIN SurveyQuestion sq
    ON sq.SurveyQuestionID = sqpa.SurveyQuestionID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')   
FROM SurveyQuestionPossibleAnswer AS x
GROUP BY x.SurveyQuestionID
```

I'm getting the right number of rows due to the group by, but the possible answers seems to be giving me every possible answer for each question.

Comment: You need a WHERE clause in your `STUFF` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f25dc/2 to tie the outer data to the list.

Comment: How in the heck did I miss that....

Comment: Depending on your actual query you could shorten your code to - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f25dc/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a way to tie the outer table to the data inside of the `STUFF`. You can do this by adding a `WHERE` clause to the subquery:

```
SELECT x.SurveyQuestionID, 
  PossibleAnswers 
    = STUFF((
              SELECT ', ' + Answer 
              FROM SurveyQuestionPossibleAnswer sqpa
              INNER JOIN SurveyQuestion sq
                ON sq.SurveyQuestionID = sqpa.SurveyQuestionID
              WHERE x.SurveyQuestionID = sq.SurveyQuestionID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')   
FROM SurveyQuestionPossibleAnswer AS x
GROUP BY x.SurveyQuestionID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f25dc/2). Or to shorten the code, you could even rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT x.SurveyQuestionID, 
  PossibleAnswers 
    = STUFF((
              SELECT ', ' + Answer 
              FROM SurveyQuestionPossibleAnswer sqpa
              WHERE x.SurveyQuestionID = sqpa.SurveyQuestionID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')   
FROM SurveyQuestion AS x
GROUP BY x.SurveyQuestionID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f25dc/5). Both will give you the same result.